# how can I make loop within a loop in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have table faq_categories with following fields

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `faq_categories` (
  `catid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoryname` varchar(37) NOT NULL,
  `parentid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `metatags` text NOT NULL,
  `sorder` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `visible` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `categoryphoto` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`catid`),
  KEY `parentid_fk` (`parentid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=52 ;
```

In my php code I have the following code :

```
$query="SELECT * FROM categories";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
    $i=0;
    while ($i < $num) {
        $id=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
        $name=mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
        $parentid=mysql_result($result,$i,"parentid");
        $categoryphoto=mysql_result($result,$i,"categoryphoto");
        $sorder=mysql_result($result,$i,"sorder");
        $visible=mysql_result($result,$i,"visible");


 echo $id;

echo $name;

// THIS IS WHAT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO IN CODEIGNITER
// HOW TO GET THE CATEGORYNAME ON BASE ON PARENTID

 if ($parentid) {

                        //echo $parentid;
                         $query1="SELECT name as parentname FROM categories WHERE id = ".$parentid; 
                         echo mysql_result(mysql_query($query1),0,"parentname");

                        } else {
                            echo "Root Category";
                        }
```

How can I do this in codeigniter? If possible, I would like to avoid joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: I think you can check [Database class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html)
Second: why don't you want use joins? If you hate it maybe you can use `FROM table1,table2` :) IMHO lesser queries is better :)

**EDIT**
Install an sql-gui (e.g. [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php), [adminer](http://www.adminer.org/)...) and try some query! An example similar what you need:

```
SELECT *, catjoin.categoryname AS parentname
FROM categories
JOIN categories AS catjoin ON (catjoin.catid=categories.parentid)
```

You can extend `catjoin.categoryname` with [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) to returns `ROOT category`.

Comment: Well, the reason that I would like to avoid joins is that I am not that good with sql statements. Another reason is that I am trying to use general models, for example my model for selecting records look like this:

Comment: [code]  public function selectOneRecord($selectWhat = array()) 
        {
            $data = array();
            $rid = $selectWhat['rid'];
            $tname = $selectWhat['tname'];
            $fname = $selectWhat['fname'];
          
            $this->db->where($fname,$rid);
            $query = $this->db->get($tname,1);
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                $data = $query->row_array();
            }
            
            $query->free_result();
            return $data;         
        } // 
        [code]

Comment: But if you can help me with the join, I will give it a try. Thanks for responding on my question, I appreciate it very much

Comment: can you post any solution for the table above? Any solution will help.

Comment: I will check that in a minute.Thanks a ton.